# Как найти проект в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Доброго времени суток, подскажите, можно ли как-то отыскать проект в Visual Studio, который создавался довольно давно, чтобы отображаться в списке "Последние" (примерно месяца 3 назад)? К сожалению, не запомнил путь сохранения и вот теперь мучаюсь в надежде найти этот код.

Answer (score 1):

Поищи в документах папку Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

Запусти на каждом диске (или вспомнишь где примерно) поиск с фильтром *.sln

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!